# Error Placement for jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery

For some reason its not putting the error messages down in the div with a class of errorContainer and I'm not sure why when there is an error, however how it looks in the jsfiddle looks messed up compared to my actual page.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/VtXdk/][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to my question.

http://jsfiddle.net/MtRn6/1/